# Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: python

Im trying to get my first "game" in Python finished, but it just wont work and i cant find the mistake...
Heres my code:

```
#Rock, Paper, Scissors
import random

userchoice = raw_input("Choose Rock paper or Scissors: ")
print userchoice
uch = 0
cch = 0
cont = 0
winner = 4

cch = random.randint(1,3)

if userchoice == "rock":
    uch = 1
    cont = 1
elif userchoice == "paper":
    uch = 2
    cont = 1
elif userchoice == "scissors":
    uch = 3
    cont = 1
else:
    print "Error"


print uch
print cch
#if cont == 1:

if   uch == 1 & cch == 1:
     winner = 0
elif uch == 1 & cch == 2:
     winner = 2
elif uch == 1 & cch == 3:
     winner = 1
elif uch == 2 & cch == 1:
     winner = 1
elif uch == 2 & cch == 2:
     winner = 0
elif uch == 2 & cch == 3:
    winner = 2
elif uch == 3 & cch == 1:
    winner = 2
elif uch == 3 & cch == 2:
     winner = 1
elif uch == 3 & cch == 3:
    winner = 0
else:
    print "Error"


if winner == 0:
    print "Even"
elif winner == 1:
    print "You win"
elif winner == 2:
    print "Computer wins"
elif winner == 4:
    print "Error2"
```

I get an Error everytime, and sometimes a wrong "Even" Answer...
I think the Error is somewhere in the part where it decides who wins...

Comment: `i cant find the mistake` and you think we can? without you telling us what the error is or what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `and` and `&`? The second one is [bitwise AND](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), and does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Need to change `&` to `and`

Answer (score 1):

This is what the bitwise and does, as you don't seem to understand:

```
 integer | binary representation |
-----------------------------------
    5    |          101          |  # bits are aligned and kept in place if
    7    |          111          |  # bits are ones, then then to base 10
-----------------------------------
    5               101
```

It's like a logical and, except with the bits. Use the keyword `and`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in your block where you compare the user choice and the computer choice, you meant to use "and" rather than "&".

Comment: What does `&&` do in Python, might I ask?

Comment: Python doesn't use symbolic logical operators so && doesn't do anything.

Comment: My bad. I have been working in ruby as well where both exist, though with different levels of precedence. I have edited the answer to correct the mistake.